# Can't get onPostExecute in AsyncTask to run, possibly can't get doInBackground either

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm designing an App for one of my classes. The goal of this app is to connect to a website, with a given HTML, and pull a certain file. This file is chosen based on input, and a new activity is created to display the data when the user clicks the display button.

My teacher wants us to use an AsyncTask to pull the data from the html, and then create the new activity. I've never had an issue with AsyncTask before, but now I can't get my onPostExecute to run. I've put testers in onPostExecute and they never run, so I assume my doInBackground is the problem. I have yet to find an answer that has solved my problem.

Here's my code, the problem happens at the bottom (Yes, I have a new xml and java for the new activity and it is in my manifest)

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Pulling Data";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        URL url = urls[0];
        int complete = 0;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = isw.read();
            while (data != 1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                data = isw.read();
                dataToPass += current;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (urlConnection != null)
                urlConnection.disconnect();

            if (!dataToPass.equals(""))
                complete = 1;

            return complete;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result == 1) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Result = 1";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, Stock_Data.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(STOCK_DATA, dataToPass);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Result != 1";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            TextView homeMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.homeMessage);
            homeMessage.setText("The website containing the data is unavailable or does not exist." +
                    "\nPlease enter:" +
                    "\n! - Intel" +
                    "\n~ - Microsoft");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `a website, with a given HTML,`. Sorry but that is nonsense. Please reread what your teacher said.